# Is it "a user" or "an user"?

Tags: grammaticality, articles

Since "*user*" starts with a *vowel*, shouldn't we use "an"? I've seen many cases of using "a".

Answer (score 220, accepted):

From [Amerenglish](http://amerenglish-grammar-2.webs.com/articles.htm):

> "An" goes before all words that begin with vowels:
>
> - An egg
>
> With two exceptions:
>
> When "u" makes the same sound as the "y" in you, or "o" makes the same sound as "w" in won, then "a" is used:
>
> - a union
> - a united front
> - a unicorn
> - a used napkin
> - a U.S. ship
> - a one-legged man

Comment: `An user` did sound incorrect; It is nice to be right.

Comment: This is missing at least one other exceptional case, when 'E' makes the same sound as the 'y' in you, like `a European`. This is mentioned in the link you provided. You could probably reword the exceptional cases to indicate that 'a' is used whenever the following word begins with the sound of a consonant, regardless of the actual letter.

Comment: I down voted because it doesn't answer the question. He assumed the OP/readers are native and could recognize the `u` in `user` is pronounced as the `y` in `you`.

Answer (score 78):

It's *a* because the first sound of *user* is not a vowel, but the consonant /j/.

‘Vowel’ and ‘consonant’ describe letters that represent vowel and consonant sounds, but they also describe the sounds themselves. A vowel is a sound made from the throat without interruption by the other vocal organs. A consonant is a sound blocked or restricted by audible friction. The initial sound of ‘user’, /j/, is interrupted by the position of the soft palate and the tongue. It is convenient to group it with the other consonants, but, because its place and manner of articulation are a little different from them, it is also known as a semi-vowel.

Comment: Please, could someone elaborate on this? I had never heard of that and I am having trouble looking for the right keywords to search for it.

Comment: ‘Vowel’ and ‘consonant’ describe letters that represent vowel and consonant sounds, but they also describe the sounds themselves. A vowel is a sound made from the throat without interruption by the other vocal organs. A consonant is a sound blocked or restricted by audible friction. The initial sound of ‘user’, /j/, is interrupted by the position of the soft palate and the tongue. It is convenient to group it with the other consonants, but, because its place and manner of articulation are a little different from them, it is also known as a semi-vowel.

Comment: There are also ambiguous words such as house and horse where depending on how you pronounce the words depends on how you use them. So if you say 'orse or 'ouse, then you will say an horse but if you pronounce the h, then you would say a horse. Which is somewhat ironic when the letter h itself would be an h and not a h.

Comment: @Cephlin: "when the letter h itself would be an h and not a h" - unless, of course, you pronounce the letter as "haitch", in which case it would be a h and not an h. ;-0

Comment: why is /j/ used to represent the sound of the first syllable in username?

Comment: @oldboy: Because j is the IPA (international phonetic alphabet) symbol for that sound, see Wikpedia's [help page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/English) for example. The slashes are [how single IPA sounds are written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Brackets_and_transcription_delimiters). This use of j is also mentioned in the third sentence of [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J) on the letter j. [Instructional materials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8twbQzumNQs) use it too. Think of hallelujah, Reykjavik, Sarajevo, Johann, etc.

Comment: ah, thanks! very similar to the 'j' in spanish as well. article use on this one kind of defies the "rule" regarding vowels and consonants as first letters